# Cannot assign value of type '[ViewController.MyStruct]' to type '[ViewController.MyOtherStruct]'

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to decode [some JSON](https://pastebin.com/sGHHk9mV) and I keep getting the error :

`Cannot assign value of type '[ViewController.Response]' to type '[ViewController.Doc]'`

As far as I can see both structs are set up the same way so I'm confused as to what the issue is here.

These are my structs:

```
struct Status: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let response: [Response]
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    let docs: [Doc]
}

struct Doc: Decodable {
    let webUrl: String
    let abstract: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case webUrl = "web_url"
        case abstract
    }

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        abstract = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .abstract)
        webUrl = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .webUrl)
    }
}
```

Error is thrown when I call my `fetchData` function in `viewDidLoad` (error on the `.success` case on `object.response`):

```
    fetchData(url: jsonUrl) { (result: FetchResult<Status>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let object): self.storyData = object.response
        print("Results \n\n\n\n \(object.response)")
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
```

EDIT: This is the array that I populate with the JSON data:

```
var storyData = [Doc]()
```

Comment: `Doc` and `Response` are completely unrelated, so it's logical that you cannot assign an array of `Response` to an array of `Doc` variable. Also you didn't post your `UIViewController` code where you define `storyData` variable, but I'm guessing you want it to be of `[Decodable]` type instead of `[Doc]`

Comment: Sorry I edited my question to add the `var storyData = [Doc]()` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storyData` is of type `[Doc]`, so you cannot assign a value of type `[Response]` to it. You need to access the `docs` property of `Response`, which you can do by calling `flatMap` on `response` to get all docs from the  response array and flatten the result to get `[Doc]` instead of `[[Doc]]`, which you can assign to `storyData`.

```
fetchData(url: jsonUrl) { (result: FetchResult<Status>) in
    switch result {
        case .success(let object): 
            self.storyData = object.response.flatMap{$0.docs}
            print("Results \n\n\n\n \(object.response)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying this gives me the error `Value of type '[ViewController.Response]' has no member 'docs'`

Comment: Ok, I see what I'm doing wrong now - thanks! Although after printing `object.response.flatMap{$0.docs` it looks like the JSON is empty (error `typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "response", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`). However that's probably a whole separate issue that I'll need to put in a different question. Thanks for your help as always David!

Comment: That means your model definitions don't match the JSON. You can use [quicktype.io](https://quicktype.io) to generate you the model classes from your JSON.

Comment: That's a great site, I actually have it open for reference right now. I've set up the structs the same way they're set up there but am still getting the error unfortunately. This is what the site generates: https://app.quicktype.io?share=r9G8eL9GjHDz0TMcUIld